# Oracle trigger causing infinite loop

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a `students` table in my Oracle database which has a field called `RECORD_NUMBER`. This field is 8 characters long and I want to create a trigger to pad the left part out with `0`s as it's inserted. This is what I have so far:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER STUDENTS_RECORD_NUMBER_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF RECORD_NUMBER ON TBL_STUDENTS 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  WHILE length(:new.RECORD_NUMBER) < 9
    LOOP
      :new.RECORD_NUMBER := LPAD(:new.RECORD_NUMBER,8,'0');
    END LOOP;
  NULL;
END;
```

However, when I try to insert a row the database connection locks up and I have to restart Oracle to use it again. Is it possible that this trigger is causing an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `record_number` is a `varchar2(8)`, then `length(:new.record_number)` will always be less than 9 and your loop will iterate endlessly.  But you don't need a loop here, just call `LPAD`

```
create or replace TRIGGER STUDENTS_RECORD_NUMBER_TRG 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF RECORD_NUMBER 
  ON TBL_STUDENTS 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.RECORD_NUMBER := LPAD(:new.RECORD_NUMBER,8,'0');
END;
```

This assumes, of course, that it really makes sense to pad the data that is physically stored in the database rather than doing something like applying the `LPAD` in a view layer.  Generally, I would expect that you'd be better served putting this sort of presentation logic in a view since views are great for implementing presentation logic.  But this trigger should do what you've asked.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, it doesn't throw any errors however when a row is inserted the trigger fails to pad the record number.

Comment: @JamesDawson - What is the data type of the `record_number` column?  Is it a `VARCHAR2(8)` or a `NUMBER`?

Answer (score 0):

Leave the entry as a number. If it needs to be displayed with padded zeroes then do so as part of the display logic.